# How do I migrate a Node code base to TypeScript without altering require statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Imagine I have two files:

```
// a.ts

const config = require('config').init()
const b = require('./b')
```

```
// b.ts

const config = require('config').init()
```

If I was to compile this using `tsc` it gives me the following error:

```
a.ts:1:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'config'.

1 const config = require('config').init()
        ~~~~~~

  b.ts:1:7
    1 const config = require('config').init()
            ~~~~~~
    'config' was also declared here.

b.ts:1:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'config'.

1 const config = require('config').init()
        ~~~~~~

  a.ts:1:7
    1 const config = require('config').init()
            ~~~~~~
    'config' was also declared here.
```

This seems to suggest it considers `a.js` and `b.js` to be in the same scope, which is inaccurate in the CommonJS system.  Is there a way I can encourage `tsc` to consider my files as scopes to stop this issue happening?

I'm converting an archaic code base, so converting all the require statements to imports would take an eternity and I'd rather do it bit by bit, instead of all at once.

Comment: From my bag of tricks : add `export {}` somewhere in your file

Comment: I strongly recommend to use native TS `import` and other TS features to easier maintain, support, extend and read code. Otherwise it's senseless to  use TS as almost JS only.